# Google Translate, translate some headlines on my website wrong. Can I "force" a new translation?

Tags: php, google-translate

I discovered that a number of reader on my website used Google Translate to translate my site into English. In response to that I’ve installed a Google Translate function on my site where readers can click on an English flag and then the site is translated into English. An easy and efficient method.

But now I’ve discovered that some headlines are translated all wrong to the point where the meaning behind the headline is completely different. Is there an option or something where I can “help” the Google Translator with the real headline so everyone gets the correct translation of it?

I tried on translate.google.com to enter my URL and then I get the option to “Suggest a better translation” but even though I enter the correct translation of the headlines, it’s only a “suggestion” and not sure that this translation will take over from the old one.

Can I “force” Google to translate specific parts of my site into the correct translation?

Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your better off translating the website yourself then offering a language switch.

It's fairly easy to do, the leg work is putting in all of the text.

Take a look at http://www.bitrepository.com/php-how-to-add-multi-language-support-to-a-website.html for a good tutorial.